# python program that Simulates the rolling of two six-sided dice for 1000 times and stores the sum values in a file

Tags: python

Write a Python program that does the following a. Simulates the rolling of two six-sided dice for 1000 times.
b. Stores the sum of the values obtained for the two dice in a file.
c. Creates a frequency table for the sum and stores it in a file.
d. Calculates the median mode and mean for the sum and displays it to the screen
• use functions whenever possible,
• All output to the file or screen should be well formatted and accompanied by indicative text,
• your program code should be well documented.

I'm having some problems in storing the results so i need help in (c)&(d)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import itertools
import random
min = 1

max = 6

N = 1000
while True:

    print("Do you want me to roll the dice? write (Yes or y)(No or n)")

    answer = input()

    if answer.lower() == "yes" or answer.lower() == "y":
        for _ in itertools.repeat(None, N):
            sum_values = open("sum values.txt", "a")
            dice_roll = random.randint(min, max)
            dice_roll1 = random.randint(min, max)
            print(f''' The numbers are ...{dice_roll}, {dice_roll1}''')
            sum_values.write(str(dice_roll))
            sum_values.write("+")
            sum_values.write(str(dice_roll1))
            sum_values.write("=")
            result = int(dice_roll) + int(dice_roll1)
            sum_values.write(str(result))
            sum_values.write("\n")
            sum_values.close()
           
    elif answer.lower() == "no" or answer.lower() == "n":

        print("Ok...")

        break

    else:

        print("Please Enter a clear choice")
```

Comment: Obiously, you do know how to write to file (this works in your code, though it can be tricky to use spaces in the file name. So, what is the real problem?

Comment: @Ronald thanks for noticing, my problem is in calculating the median, mode and mean for the sum

Comment: Do C & D part after while loop.

Comment: And the frequency I guess...?

Comment: @Ronald Ah, yes exactly..... my bad

Comment: @Pygirl thank you for the advice i should try it rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to help with the frequency, you can use a dictionary which you should create before the `while` loop:

```
freq = {}
```

Then you can use `str(result)` as key in the dictionary which you increase if it already exists, and else create the key and set it to 1:

```
...
result = int(dice_roll) + int(dice_roll1)
key=str(result)
if key in freq:
    freq[key] += 1  # increase if already exists
else:
    freq[key] = 1   # create new
...
```

Once you have this dictionary, you should be able to calculate the mean, mode and median.

Comment: still doesn't store the sum
It only stores the last sum in the loop

Comment: When you implement it correctly, it gives you a dictionary, representing the number of times a certain sum-of-two-dices occurs. Something like: `{'6': 554, '4': 340, '9': 424, '8': 566, '5': 461, '11': 204, '10': 341, '3': 230, '12': 102, '7': 659, '2': 119}`. With the data in this dictionary you can calculate mean, median and mode.